# Como ordenar uma lista 1 pra N com expression lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, expressões-lambda

Preciso ordenar uma lista e não sei por onde começar.

Tentei aplicar o código abaixo baseado em algumas postagem, por exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq , mas realmente não sei como fazer:

```
var ret = objCliente.ListaDeClientes();
var retCli = ret.OrderBy(x => x.ID_PAI).ThenBy(x => x.ID_PAI_FILHO);
```

Alguém pode me direcionar ? ou mostra um exemplo de como fazer ? 
A lista do lado esquerdo está desorganizada e preciso deixar como a lista que esta á direita:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não importa as listas, apresente a estrutura das duas classes. Ao que parece você quer uma lista de pais ordenada, com seus filhos ordenados... Me parece que esses objetos deveriam estar aninhandos e não no mesmo nível de hierarquia

Comment: @Leandro Angelo a classe contém outros atributos que não apresentei aqui porque é irrelevante, essa lista retorna de procedure de um legado do jeito que postei, o problema é que preciso ordenar essa lista do jeito que coloquei no post.

Comment: Não explica a ordenação, qual é a lógica da sua ordenação

Answer (score 0):

Entendi sua necessidade. Mas você precisa que isso seja feito especificamente em uma expressão lambda? Não pode usar LINQ? Caso possa, vai aí um exemplo:

```
List<Objeto> retAux = new List<Objeto>();
List<Objeto> ret = objCliente.ListaDeClientes();

// Recupera os objetos pai
var listaRetPais = ret.Where(x => x.ID_PAI > 0 && x.ID_PAI_FILHO == 0).ToList();

// Percorre os objetos pai
foreach (var retPai in listaRetPais)
{
    // Popula o pai em uma lista auxiliar
    retAux.Add(new Objeto()
    {
        ID_PAI = retPai.ID_PAI,
        FILHO = retPai.FILHO,
        ID_PAI_FILHO = retPai.ID_PAI_FILHO
    });

    // Percorre os objetos filhos do objeto pai atual
    foreach (var retFilho in ret.Where(x => x.ID_PAI == retPai.ID_PAI).ToList())
    {
        // Popula os filhos
        retAux.Add(new Objeto()
        {
            ID_PAI = retFilho.ID_PAI,
            FILHO = retFilho.FILHO,
            ID_PAI_FILHO = retFilho.ID_PAI_FILHO
        });
    }
}
```

No fim do processo você terá sua lista ordenada da maneira que deseja.